# How can I show dates 10 years into the future?

Tags: php, wordpress, date

I'm writing a science fiction Wordpress blog set 10 years into the future.
I basically need all posts to display as if they are 10 years from now.

Eg. posts needs to display as:
February 7, 2021 instead of
February 7, 2011

This will be for every post that I write.

How can I automatically add 10 years to every post date?
(And where would I put that code?)

Currently, the Wordpress PHP is calling the date with `<?php the_time(__('M j, Y')) ?>`.

How would I have to change this?

Answer (score 5):

Not sure that you can modify Wordpress to do it for you, but here's some quick code to do it yourself, using the [`strtotime`](http://php.net/function.strtotime.php) function:

```
echo "Posted: ".date("M j, Y", strtotime("+10 years", $article_date));
```

Comment: And that prints out: "Posted: Feb 15, 2021"

Comment: Thanks Muddybruin.... this is getting close to what I need but `date('M j, Y', strtotime('+10 years'));` gives me today's date 10 years into the future, 

wheras I need it to be the [i]article/post [/i]date 10 years into the future. I tried `the_time('M j, Y', strtotime('+10 years'));` but it doesn't add the 10 years when I do this...

Any ideas that would get me over the finish line?

thanks in advance!

Comment: echo "Posted: ".date("M j, Y", strtotime("+10 years", get_the_time()));